# How to numerically solve ODE's in R more quickly

Tags: r, optimization, ode

I'm currently working on solving and optimizing the parameters of the Lotka-Volterra set of differential equations in R. In order to optimize the solution, I need to solve the ODE's upwards of 10,000 times, so I need to find a quicker way to solve them.

I'm currently using the 'ode' command in package deSolve (version 1.20). I'm running R version 3.4.2 in RStudio (version 1.1.419) on Windows 10 with 4 GB of RAM. The code reproduced below takes about 16 seconds to run. While that doesn't sound so bad, for tens of thousands of run over a larger dataset, the time is prohibitive. I have performed the code on a super cluster computer across 28 cores; however, it is still time consuming.

```
start <- Sys.time()
library(deSolve)


##CONTROL PANEL##
state <- c(4,1)
time <- seq(0,9,1)

parms <- c(alpha_star = 4.577,
    theta_a = 2.334,
    beta_star = 4.560,
    theta_b = 0.085,
    delta_star = 2.836,
    theta_d = 2.496, 
    gamma_star = 1.254,
    theta_g = 0.031)

extVar <- c(154.35, 150.8, 150.85, 152, 152.15, 153.3, 155.1, 154.65, 156.35, 152.5)


data <- data.frame(x = c(4,5,2,5,4,7,8,3,7,10), 
                   y = c(1,3,3,4,9,9,2,2,6,4))



##LOTKA-VOLTERRA##
LotVmod <- function (Time, State, pars) {
    with(as.list(c(State, pars)), {
        alpha <- alpha_star + theta_a*sigimp(Time)
        beta <- beta_star  + theta_b*sigimp(Time)
        gamma <- gamma_star + theta_g*sigimp(Time)
        delta <- delta_star + theta_d*sigimp(Time)
    dx = alpha*State[1]-(beta*State[1]*State[2])
    dy = (-delta*State[2]) + (gamma*State[1]*State[2])
  return(list(c(dx, dy)))
  })
}


sigimp <- approxfun(time, extVar, rule=2)


out <- ode(state, time, LotVmod, parms, rtol = 1e-15, maxsteps = 500000)

print(Sys.time() - start)
```

I would like to shorten the time running the above code by as much as possible. I'm open to any type of solution. Also, if this is a question best suited for another place or another discipline, I'd greatly appreciate you pointing me in the right direction!

Thank you so much!

Comment: There are a few things you can try. 1) Ask for less precision. `rtol = 1e-15` seems to be *crazily* small for relative tolerance. Are you *sure* you need it that small? Try a few values and compare the solutions to get an intuitive feel for the parameter. 2) Use a different ODE solver. You can do this with the `method` parameter. I often use `vode` and `lsoda`. 3) Rewrite your function in C/C++. Last resort, but it reduces runtime.

Comment: Do you get substantially shorter run times when changing `rtol = 1e-15` to `rtol = 1e-10`? What is your rationale to using `rtol = 1e-15`? Did you check that this tolerance is actually reached? If the solver reduces every step size to the minimal advance, this will accumulate floating point noise and give an unusable result.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding! To clarify, I've tried changing the tolerance using the default and also setting it to `rtol = 1e-10` as suggested. However, I get either poor results or `NaN` when the tolerance isn't set to `rtol = 1e-15` for the actual data.